# Is there any difference between handling TCP connection in .netCore vs .netFramework?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I'm trying to write a stable server that can handle many concurrent TCP connections and can be scaled up.

I have a `class library` that is my `TCP Server` and a `Server Host` console app that is the entry point to the server and execute the server in console;
I have two versions of `Server Host` that are exactly the same (I mean same lines of code with no difference) but in different frameworks :

1. `.netFramework4.8` console app
2. `.net7` console app

Everything's good in the first app (`.net framework 4.8`) but I have a situation in the second one (`.net7`).

*b.t.w: I'm using a port monitoring tool (`Nirsoft CurrPorts`) to see the current port states in my OS.*

I'm sending many concurrent requests (e.g: 3000+) to both of them. The first one (`.netFramework4.8`) can handle the connections correctly; It releases the port after its job done, and I see just a little of `TIME_WAIT` ports in my monitoring tool.
But the second one (`.net7`), I don't know what happened, but I see a lot of `TIME_WAIT` ports in my monitoring tool, and because of this, I will run out of free/available dynamic TCP ports and cannot open a new connection! (I know it's sth related to `TCP Port Exhaustion` and this `TIME_WAIT` state is related to `TCP Protocol` handshake and the timeout differs in each `OS`)

**So my question is, Is it any difference in handling TCP connection and states in `.net framework` to `.net core`?
And what should I do? How to investigate the situation?**

---

I also increased my dynamic ports range (`MaxUserPort`) in my OS (`windows 10`). But I didn't change the default value of `TcpTimedWaitDelay` setting.

Comment: As to how to investigate, 1) create a minimum reproducible code sample for each and update your answer, 2) investigate deviations from .NET Framework to .NET (core), 3) are there differences in configuration in your apps? 4) are there differences in defaults at the socket layer? Finally, .NET Core *does* do something different for sockets, but at the same time *does* defer to OS socket implementations (e.g. Winsock). So not sure how that would fit in, but something to think about.

Comment: @Kit 1) Okay, I'm on it 2) I didn't get it 3) no, they are just the same, I just copied and pasted from `netframework` to `.net7` console app 4) Both of them are in the same environment with the same OS with the same OS configurations.